# Is it possible to Union starting from an empty var?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, union, var

I need somethings like:

```
var myList;

foreach (MyObject myObject in myObjects)
{
    myList = myList.Union(myObject.Items.Cast<Item>());
}
```

but seems I cannot initializate an empty var. Solutions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`var` doesn't work like that, it uses type inference to assign the type based on what's after the equals.

Also, that'd throw a null exception as you're trying to access`myList` **before** you've initialised it (it'd be `null`). Try this:

```
IEnumerable<Item> myList = myObjects.SelectMany(m => m.Items.Cast<Item>());
```

Comment: I wouldn't describe it as "lazy evaluation" - it's type inference.

Comment: nice! Works also with `var myList = myObjects.SelectMany(m => m.Items.Cast<Item>());`

Comment: @markzzz Yeah you can keep the `var`, as long as you assign it something first :)

Answer (score 2):

`Union` returns the same type as it takes, considering you're using the `IEnumerable<Item>` inside it, then:

```
var myList = Enumerable.Empty<Item>();
```

Answer (score 2):

This isn't a matter of `Union` - it's a matter of trying to read from *any* uninitialized local variable.

You could use:

```
var myVar = Enumerable.Empty<Item>();
```

... or just use `SelectMany` as shown by mattytommo, possibly with a call to `Distinct()` to get just distinct elements (as `Union` would).

Answer (score 1):

You have to specify the type of the variable, and you have to start with an empty collection, for example:

```
IEnumerable<Item> myList = new List<Item>();
```

Answer (score 0):

The compiler can't know which type you want to create so

```
var myList;
```

isn't enough to tell the compiler what type `myList` has.
You can do

```
List<Item> myList;
```

but the call to `.Union` will give you a NullReferenceException.

So why not start with an empty list

```
List<Item> myList = new List<Item>
```

or an IEnumerable?

```
IEnumerable<Item> myEnumerable = Enumerable.Empty<Item>()
```